# Как передать строку, содержащую путь в GET-запросе?

Tags: javascript, строки, razor

Есть такой код в представлении:

```
...
<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Images</h4>
<hr />
<form>
    <input type="text" id="path" placeholder="path"/>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name"/>
    <div id="convert" class="btn btn-primary">Convert</div>
</form>

<script>
    var path = $('#path').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var convert = document.getElementById('convert');
    convert.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var url = 'https://localhost:44372/Images/ImageToByte/?strImageFilePath="'+ path + '"&imageName="'+name + '"';
        fetch(url);
    });
</script>
```

Суть в том, что я хочу просто в форму вводить путь к картинке на компьютере, чтобы потом загрузить ее в бд как varbinary. 
Но когда я делаю запрос, в метод приходят параметры
strImageFilePath = "\"\"" и imageName = "\"\""
Как правильно передать параметры?
Например, "C:/Images/1.jpg"

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: Но вообще, выглядит так, что у Вас `path` и `name` оказываются пустыми. Вы это проверяли?

Comment: @Yaant спасибо большое за наводку. Довольно глупая ошибка произошла, я до этого проверял в консоли специально значение полей, но не учел, что у меня переменные объявлены вне функции, поэтому они пустыми оказались на момент запроса